# get innerHeight of <object data="url.html"> and set it as style.height of that object

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 columns.

Column 1 holds my navigation.

Column 2 holds my content.

I used `getElementByID` and `setAttribute('data','url')` of an object whenever someone `onclick` a navigation.

My issue is tag `<object>` does not support 'height:100%;' in css, so I'm trying to use javascript to get the innerHeight of a html file and set it's style.height to that data.

Not sure if this is the right way or if there are other methods to load a html file in `<object>` and display the full height of a content.

```
<body onload="load_a()">

<section class="grid-layout">
    <div id="nav-panel">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href ="#" onclick="load_a()">
                    <p>A</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href ="#" onclick="load_b()">
                    <p>B</p>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="grid-layout">
    <div id="content-panel">    
        <object onloadstart="object_height" id="content" type="text/html"></object>
    </div>
</section>

</body>

<script>
function object_height(){
    var contentHeight = document.getElementById("content");
    document.getElementById("content").style.height = contentHeight.innerHeight;
}

function load_a(){
    document.getElementById("content").setAttribute('data', 'a.html');
}

function load_b(){
    document.getElementById("content").setAttribute('data', 'b.html');
}
</script>
```

Is there anyway that when I click on navigation A, container loads a.html and when I click on navigation B, container loads b.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case your external files are on **the same domain**, you can access the content Document of your <object> and get its dimensions from there.

```
const obj = document.getElementById('YOUR_OBJECT');
obj.onload = e => {
  const doc = obj.contentDocument;
  obj.width = doc.documentElement.offsetWidth;
  obj.height = doc.documentElement.offsetHeight;
};
```

[As a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/buv6f9jk/) since StackSnippet's null-origined frames are never same-domain.

---

In case your external files are on a different domain, but **you control their content**, you can pass this information through [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) method.

```js
const obj = document.getElementById('obj');

window.addEventListener('message', (evt) => {
  const msg = evt.data;
  console.log(evt);
  // a simple check to be sure we are talking to #obj's content
  if(msg.type === "set-size") {
    obj.width = msg.width;
    obj.height = msg.height;
  }
});


const frame_content = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html {height: 2800px; width: 500px; background: ivory }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  Hello
  <script>
    parent.postMessage({
      type: 'set-size',
      width: document.documentElement.offsetWidth,
      height: document.documentElement.offsetHeight
    }, '*');
  <\/script>
  </body>
</html>`;

obj.data = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([frame_content], { type: 'text/html'}))
```

```css
#obj {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<object id="obj" ></object>
```

---

In case your external files are on a different domain, but you can not controls their content, you're stuck.